# URI to connect step function from api-gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, terraform-provider-aws

[image: api-gateway]
I'm trying to create the terraform for the above `aws_api_gateway_integration`. I'm not able to create the `aws_api_gateway_integration` as it returns the error

> Error creating API Gateway Integration: BadRequestException: AWS ARN for integration must contain path or action

Please find the terraform code snippet.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "approve_get_integration" {
  rest_api_id                 = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.approval_api.id}"
  resource_id                 = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.approve_resource.id}"
  http_method                 = "${aws_api_gateway_method.approve_get_Method.http_method}"
  type                        = "AWS"
  integration_http_method     = "POST"
  uri                         = "arn:aws:apigateway:ap-southeast-1:states:SendTaskSuccess/${var.step-function-arn}"
  timeout_milliseconds        = 29000
}
```

I'm trying to **sendTaskuccess** to the aws stepfunction activity.

Answer (score 1):

You must be using the following as the `uri` to send the task status to StepFunction Activity

```
uri = "arn:aws:apigateway:${var.region}:states:action/SendTaskFailure"
```